# Vue: Access values over api (nested)

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, mustache

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

In my template I try to show data which I receiver over an api call. When I log the api get response this is what I receive:
[image]

Now I try to show the data in location with the following code:
`{{ userdetails.location.location_name }}`

My script looks like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      userdetails: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getUserData() {
      DataService.getUserById()
        .then((response) => {
          this.userdetails = response.data;
          console.log(response);
        }) 

...

  created() {
    this.getUserData();
  },
```

The strange thing is, I can see the location_name in my application. But I also receive an error:[image]

I think I made somewhere a mistake, but I can't find it. Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for all your tipps!

Comment: also you can specify the exact location_name as your data,
```data(){
return {
userdetails :{
location : {
location_name : 'test'
}
}
}
```

Comment: @TheFool I mean mustache syntax from vue (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start, when the template tries to access `userdetails.location.location_name`, it is an empty list, so you will see the error. Only once the `DataService` updated `userdetails` will the nested properties exist.

The easiest way to prevent this is to start out with `userdetails` as something which is 'falsey' and then use `v-if` to determine whether to render:

```
<div v-if="userdetails">{{userdetails.location.location_name}}</div>

data() {
return {
  userdetails: undefined,
};
```

},

Note however that if your `DataService` could ever return a dict which doesn't have the `location` property, you will need to do more testing in `v-if` to determine if it can be rendered.

Comment: Thank you! It works great with my location_name. Do you have also an idea how I coud display the name of my attributes in this file? I have an array there. 

"attributes": [
        {
            "attribute": {
                "attribute_id": 17,
                "attribute_name": "gelassen",
                "attribute_category": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "attribute": {
                "attribute_id": 16,
                "attribute_name": "professionell",
                "attribute_category": 1
            }
        },